# Should we add a suite of test tags?

Tags: feature-request, tags, tag-synonyms

In some countries, the UK and the US are the first that come to mind, standardised tests for entering higher education seems to be the norm. I noticed when editing tags that someone has posted a question with the tag `sat` and did not understand what that tag could be – I read it as ‘sat’, not ‘S.A.T.’ I therefore suggest three things:

1. All tags related to standardised tests, should begin with `examen-` with `test-` as a synonym (following the format already established by preferring Latin forms where reasonably applicable).
2. I would further suggest (though read below) that we proactively establish the tags `examen-sat`, `examen-o-level` and perhaps `examen-a-level` and their respective synonyms (`test-sat`, `test-o-level`, `test-a-level`)
3. Finally, I would suggest, if possible, that all questions related to standardised tests, can be found via the supertags `examen` or `test`.

Now concerning point two, in the chat it was said that we do not make tags in case they be useful later. Pondering this, I came to the conclusion that I am certain several of the initial tags for word-classes were created ahead of time, as the site administrators knew they would come up. In the continuing conversation, it was suggested I take it to meta, as my suggestion was for a broader tag system. It was suggested that the prefixed tags are synonyms; I agree with that, but would suggest that the tag chosen to be displayed would include the prefix.

I do not know what the standardised tests of the relevant countries are, except the SAT for the US and either O-level or A-level (or both?) for the UK. In any case, as I argued in the chat, I believe as this site grows, we should expect to find more people searching for answers here in relation to tests and examinations they have to pass. Being proactive about this could help us steer traffic here and continue growing the site.

───

P. S.: I just realised why *sight* and *site* are spelt differently: The first is the same as *Sicht* or (NO) *sikt*, whereas the latter is from *situs*. Oh ye great shifters of vowels, how ye have confused thy people.

Comment: Why not just "standardized-tests" and make SAT link to it? I don't love using Latin for our tags (especially since more than half aren't even in Latin), but I especially don't like half-Latin/half-English tags! That's just too confusing. (Will write up an answer later if it's still necessary.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tags can only be created by adding them to questions.
I would apply the same principle to tag systems, not creating them preemptively but only as needed.
We do not have lots of different questions on tests like SAT, so a system of tags like that sounds overly complicated.

I like the idea cmw gives in a comment: Just create a single tag `standardized-tests`.
We can add all the tags we like for SAT and other tests, but make the synonyms of that.
We can have everything under a single tag now and split it up later if the need arises.

Comment: Do remember to include the -ised spelling too! I think this is a good solution. I would also like to suggest that the latin tag is `examen`.

Comment: @CannedMan I went ahead and edited the tags of the SAT question, creating `standardized-tests` with merged synonyms `examina` and the version in *-ised*. The SAT tag is synonymized too but not merged, so that we can separate different test tags later if the need arises.